# Android DSP - Trouble with AudioTrack and Sub-Audible Signals

Tags: android, signal-processing

I'm having some trouble getting the AudioTrack class to do what I want it to do. I'm trying to make an app that first lets the user draw a single-cycle waveform on the screen, and then outputs an arbitrary number of cycles of that waveform at an arbitrary frequency through the headphone out. For the primary use, the frequency will be below the audible range, something like 1/60Hz - 20Hz  (If anyone's familiar with Eurorack/modular synths, I'm hoping to use the headphone out as a CV source).

The problem I'm having is that the AudioTrack seems to output a highly inaccurate reproduction of the waveform  at the low end of this frequency range, even though it does output an accurate reproduction at the high end. The lower the frequency gets, the more the waveform gets 'squished' to the left on my oscilloscope. The pictures below show this phenomenon on a waveform that is supposed to start each cycle low and increase ***linearly*** to a max value, but this phenomenon happens with other waveshapes too.

So far, I have the app set up (1) to create an ArrayList to hold the data points from the user's input, (2) to convert the ArrayList into a float[] to feed to the AudioTrack, and (3) to setup the AudioTrack and write the float[] to it when needed. Since the ArrayList and float[] both maintain an accurate reproduction of the waveform, I'm pretty sure my problem is at (3), or else it's a hardware limitation of my phone/scope.

Here's the relevant code for the AudioTrack.

Method that (re)initializes the AudioTrack:

```
public void updateTrackForWave(Waveform wave, Context context) {
    if (wave.getInterpolatedWaveData() == null) return;

    int sampleRate = Integer.parseInt(
            ((AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE))
                    .getProperty(AudioManager.PROPERTY_OUTPUT_SAMPLE_RATE));

    if (wave.getOutputChannel() == Waveform.OutputChannelEnum.left) {
        if (mTrackL != null) mTrackL.release();
        mTrackL = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT,
                Float.BYTES * wave.getInterpolatedWaveData().length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        mTrackL.setVolume(AudioTrack.getMaxVolume());
    } else if (wave.getOutputChannel() == Waveform.OutputChannelEnum.right) {
        if (mTrackR != null) mTrackR.release();
        mTrackR = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT,
                Float.BYTES * wave.getInterpolatedWaveData().length,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
        mTrackR.setVolume(AudioTrack.getMaxVolume());
    }
}
```

Method that plays AudioTrack:

```
private void playWaveOnTrack(Waveform wave, AudioTrack track) {
    if (track == null) return;

    if (track.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (wave.isCycleMode()) track.setLoopPoints(0,
                wave.getInterpolatedWaveData().length, -1);
        else if (wave.isOneShotMode()) track.setLoopPoints(0,
                wave.getInterpolatedWaveData().length, 0);

        if (track.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_PAUSED) {
            track.play();
        } else if (track.getPlayState() == AudioTrack.PLAYSTATE_STOPPED) {
            track.write(wave.getInterpolatedWaveData(), 0,
                    wave.getInterpolatedWaveData().length, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING);
            track.play();
        }
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that wave.getInterpolatedWaveData() returns the float[] from (3) above.

Anyways, any help you could spare on this would be greatly appreciated! Not sure if I've made a mistake in the code I have, or if there's some code I should add (maybe an AudioEffect of some kind?), or if I'm asking too much of my phone, or what.

PS I'm new here and to Android programming in general, so please do point out any forum norms I should be following but am not, or any alternative coding approaches I might not know about.

Pictures:

[Waveform at 100Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ny57o.jpg)

[Waveform at 10Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozTsW.jpg)

[Waveform at 2Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phxfq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's a hardware limitation of your phone. In order to avoid a constant DC current flowing through each headphone speaker, they are [capacitively coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_coupling) -- each channel is in series with one or more capacitors. This gives your output waveform a [time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant); the average voltage level of the waveform will always tend towards 0 (GND), which makes it impossible to output DC, or even low-frequency signals.